# Error logging in New Relic for .Net Core Worker (IHostedService) Hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, newrelic, azure-app-service-plans, ihostedservice

I’m trying to integrate Logging for .Net Worker Application (IHostedService) which is hosted on Azure App Service ( Linux App Service Plan)

I followed the instructions defined in this link https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/install-net-agent-azure-web-apps/#nuget-install-net-core

But, unable to see the data under the `APM section` for `New Relic` Dashboard.

If anyone tried this approach before, please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured it using instructions provided here : https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/other-installation/install-net-agent-docker-container/